# Spark with Scala: compute a table by executing function on each possible pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapreduce

I am completely new to Scala/Spark and I am trying to create from scratch a Spark application that computes the exact [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) between `n` sets of integers (you don't need to know what it is to answer this question).

I have a Dataframe where each row is a set of integers, for example:

```
var sets = List(Set(1, 5, 7, 4), Set(3, 5, 0), Set(10, 1, 5)).toDF
```

and a function `jacsim(s1, s2)` that returns the Jaccard similarity between two sets. I want to define a function that given the `sets` dataframe returns another dataframe that contains at position (i, j) the result of `jacsim(sets(i), sets(j))`. How can I do that?

Additionally: Is it goot idea of using the resulting dataframe as a table? I am reading that Spark does not "like" rows being accessed by index as this hinders parallelism. Should I return a dataframe with a single row and each possible pair as a new column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned accessing spark dataframe using indexes is not allowed.
Here is one solution using scala spark dataframe :

```
var sets = List(Set(1, 5, 7, 4), Set(3, 5, 0), Set(10, 1, 5)).toDF("sets")
    .withColumn("i",monotonically_increasing_id()) // to create indexes


val jaccardSimUDF = udf((set1: Seq[Int], set2: Seq[Int]) => set1.sum +  set2.sum) // dummy function, replace it with your implementation of Jaccard similarity

val resDF = sets.crossJoin(sets.withColumnRenamed("sets", "sets2").withColumnRenamed("i", "j"))
                .withColumn("jaccardSim", jaccardSimUDF($"sets", $"sets2"))
```

Basically we need to do a cross join of your dataframe against itself to have all combinations. Then we can apply a "user defined function" (UDF) to compute jaccard similarities. Note that I created indexes for conveniency.

Now if you **really** want to have a matrix you will need to reshape this dataframe but this is not spark essence.

**As pointed out in the comment** jaccard similarity function is symmetric
so you can filter unnecessary indexes, like this :

```
val resDF = sets.crossJoin(sets.withColumnRenamed("sets", "sets2").withColumnRenamed("i", "j"))
            .filter($"i" < $"j")
            .withColumn("jaccardSim", jaccardSimUDF($"sets", $"sets2"))
```

It may seem ugly as it still involves a full crossjoin but as spark relies on lazy computation and Catalyst optimizer it is not really a full crossjoin in practice. So I don't think there is a better solution.

Comment: In case the operation `jaccardSimUDF` is symmetric (as in the example). Is there a way to prevent crossJoin to repeat index pairs (e.g. i:1, j:3 = i:3, j:1)?

Comment: That 's right ! Thanks for the comment. I edited the answer to show a better solution in case of symmetric function.